# Pickling lists in a for loop

Tags: python, list, dictionary, pickle

I have created a program which creates long lists of data. Eventually I want to aggregate those lists into a dataframe - but it takes hours to run and might crash in that time due to errors or exceptions. I will fix that but in the mean time I want to make the lists persistent so the program can start again from where it left off.

First question: is pickle a suitable way to do this?

My method: To pickle the lists I work through a list of variables (strings) which are the list names (listnames). Then try to load each one from pickle, and if that fails because the file doesn't exist, then it will go to create a blank list. The lists are all put into a dictionary. Each list is then pickled as list_name.pickle.

```
listnames=["listname1","listname2","listname3","listname4","listname5","listname6","slistname7"]
dct = {}

for i in listnames:
    picknm=i+".pickle"
    try:
        dct[i]= pickle.load(open(picknm, "rb"))
        print("List ",i," loaded from pickle")
    except:
        dct['%s' % i] = []
        print("List ",i," failed to load from pickle. List is blank: ",dct[i]," Saving to pickle as",picknm)
        pickle.dump(open(dct[i],picknm,"wb"))
```

I can't get the last line of code to work. The error is "TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)", however, I think I need to pickle the list as "something.pickle" which is a string.

Also please can you generally critique my code. Thanks

Comment: Surely you can see that `open(dct[i],picknm,"wb")` can't be correct?

Comment: @Aran-Fey no I didn't see that. Sometimes you can't see the errors in your own code, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the arguments wrong for pickle dump.

```
pickle.dump(dct[i], open(picknm,"wb"))
```

First the data, then the file handle.
But don't really see the meaning of saving an empty list if it fails to open?

Comment: Thank you for answering! I'd overlooked my error.

So what I mean by "saving an empty list if it fails to open" is the program will try to open a pickle file containing the list, but if the pickle file does not exist, then it will create an empty list e.g. ' listname1=[]  ' and then pickle that list e.g. 'pickle.dump(dct[i], open(picknm,"wb")) '

Comment: Alright :) I get it. But the question is resolved now?

Comment: Yes it is. Any other comments on my code would be helpful. 

Thanks for your input!

Comment: Some other comments, you index the dictionary differently, you will get the same result but it looks weird. ``dct[i]`` in the try block and ``dct['%s' % i]`` in the except block.

Comment: Thanks for your help.